# How to have an icon on the edge of a button?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that is supposed to show the tick icon on the top-right edge of the button, upon selected. Placing the tick icon partially over the button and partially out of the button seems to be a challenge. I was wondering if you can help me with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us, in the question, what you have tried.  Not with pictures, but with the code itself

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Also, a button (as in "a standard HTML button element") has no "selected" state. Are you aiming at something like a button but behaving like a checkbox?

Comment: This is not a standard HTML button, its a series of divs with various positions (absolute & relative) that give the "illusion" of a button

Answer (score 1):

You can make top right circle with `before` element

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    transform: translate(3rem, 3rem);
} 

button:before {
    content: attr(data);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: skyblue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right:-10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button data="&check;" class="badge-top-right">Button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help Shah. Do you think this can be used as a tab button that carries if condition?

Comment: yep, you can also do like that

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<button data="i" class="badge-top-right">Button</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
} 

button:before {
  content: attr(data);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px .  ;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border:1px solid grey;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right:-10px;
  left:auto;
}
```

You can see the result here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjfn6t

Comment: You can put your code in a "snippet" here so that we can see the results without needing to access a third-party website.